# How would a nosql schema be designed to relate users to "friends" who are actually other users?

Tags: mongodb, scaling, relation, nosql

```
User {
    _id: "my_user",
    name: "john smith",
    email: "blah@test.com,
    friends: [
      *More Users*
    ]
}
```

Do I rewrite the User data of friends? Everytime I "add a friend" do I put in the data again or do I "relate" to another User _id field?

Comment: This is asked a lot. Read this as a starter: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/. There is no perfect answer. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document structure should be based on your data access patterns i.e. the way that your program will access the data. In the example you've given above you're dealing with a one to many relationship because there will only be one "John Smith" to many friends. Friends of "John Smith" could be friends with each other which you can deal with by using Friends '_id', placed within an array as you've done so. This will reduce the risk of anomalies when modifying the data.

```
User1 {
  _id: "my_user1",
  name: "john smith",
  email: "blah@test.com,
  friends: [
    "my_user2",
    "my_user3",
    "my_user4",
  ]
}

User2 {
  _id: "my_user1",
  name: "john smith",
  email: "blah@test.com,
  friends: [
    "my_user1",
    "my_user3",
    "my_user4",
  ]
}
```

Another option is to embed the data but this could lead to duplicates and modification anomalies so should be avoided unless you need to do it for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks. So I would access a friends User data by using two find() calls right, as in there's no way of using one? And what do you think of using _id as a user_name and not and objectid?

Comment: The number of find calls would depend on your application. The code above creates a link between two documents so that you know who each user's friends are. I'm going on the basis that you have a number of users any one of which might be friends with another - is this correct?

Comment: If you use user_name as an _id you could get duplicates. In your application assign the object_id to a variable and use this to update the friends array.

Comment: @user979663 [this article](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/43082387880/mongodb-indexing-tip-1-find-your-friends-recent) could also be useful